# PHP - How to Automatically Post Form in Another Website and Parse the Result

Tags: php, curl

I am new to screen-scaraping and curl. I am planning to create a website like what http://www.skyscanner.com.my/ is doing that will allow a user to pull the origin, destination  and date from the http://airasia.com website. Then the website return the flight schedule and ticket price to the user. The following is my code so far:

code:

```
<?php

$post_data['Origin']=$_POST['origin'];
$post_data['Destination']=$_POST['destination'];
$post_data['From']=$_POST['departDate'];
$post_data['To']=$_POST['returnDate'];


foreach ($post_data as $key => $value)
{ 
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);


$curl_connection = curl_init('https://booking.airasia.com/search.aspx');

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
                curl_error($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
echo $result;
?>
```

The above do not return me any result from air asia. So i need some guidance to continue my task. Thank You

Comment: Do you think stack-overflow is used by bunch of fools. its not a plate-form to heir someone for your task and he will  give you code for your work. try yourself and do some google also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

**This Worked:**

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: mobile.airasia.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";

$post = 'hash=61582ddd1b6ab8782ad63f1a6c6c1e46&trip-type=round-trip&origin=PEK&destination=SGN&date-depart-d=25&date-depart-my=2015-04&date-return-d=30&date-return-my=2015-04&passenger-count=1&child-count=0&infant-count=0&currency=MYR&depart-sellkey=&return-sellkey=&depart-details-index=&return-details-index=&depart-faretype=&return-faretype=&action=search&btnSearch=Search';
$url = 'https://mobile.airasia.com/en/search';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
 // Get the cookies:

  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  echo $data
```

Request Header.

```
POST /en/search HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Host: mobile.airasia.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 366
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 04:02:14 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Server: redishot
Set-Cookie: locale=en; expires=Mon, 20-Apr-2015 05:02:11 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: currency=MYR; expires=Mon, 20-Apr-2015 05:02:11 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=p8mjtiiga4615pnhuu6vl1htiqkqsn7v; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=CDFDE3A70C862943856FF6079178A94249700C674BDFF1E117C02BF52443FE13448AB71BEA2EA3F41C01293A39C3579A0A03905034DA565F71B4820BD1807C5558B22ED5E0;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=1800
Vary: Accept-Encoding
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is the data you need from the returned HTML

- Flight No.
- Flight Time
- Cost

.

```
Results","position":1}]}}' data-disabled><div class="smallFont farelist no-discount "><div class=flight-no>D7  317</div><div class=flight-time>02:15<br>12:10</div><div class=flight-info><div class=box><div class=total-price>MYR 2,091.42</div>

Results","position":2}]}}' data-disabled><div class="smallFont farelist no-discount "><div class=flight-no>D7  317</div><div class=flight-time>02:15<br>12:55</div><div class=flight-info><div class=box><div class=total-price>MYR 2,106.26</div>

Results","position":3}]}}' data-disabled><div class="smallFont farelist no-discount "><div class=flight-no>D7  317</div><div class=flight-time>02:15<br>15:50</div><div class=flight-info><div class=box><div class=total-price>MYR 2,483.82</div>
```

**end of update**

---

Do not prepend the "?" in the post data.

This is the format in the php manual:

```
 $post = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';
```

---

You cannot curl `http://booking.airasia.com/search.aspx` because it requires javaScript.

You have to use the mobile site.  When use a Browser to see the HTTP Request and Response Headers do it with JavaScript disabled on the Browser.

Use:

```
https://mobile.airasia.com/en/search
```

The problem is the mobile site is not functioning correctly right now and says to try later.  so I could not get any further.

Regarding the post

This is what is being posted by the search:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 366
hash=26edce4024c5611451a2a95a74e2bf01
&trip-type=round-trip
&origin=KUL
&destination=OOL&date-depart-d=20
&date-depart-my=2015-04&date-return-d=25
&date-return-my=2015-04
&passenger-count=1
&child-count=0&infant-count=0
&currency=MYR
&depart-sellkey=
&return-sellkey=
&depart-details-index=
&return-details-index=
&depart-faretype=
&return-faretype=
&action=search
&btnSearch=Search
```

Because their form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` your are almost doing the $post_string correctly.  You can use an array for the post data but if value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data`, which should be OK.

Because it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  you must urlencode `$post_string` :

```
$post_string` = urlencode(implode ('&', $post_items));
```

To get the cookies, you do not need, and possibly never will need:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
```

Remove it.

You will be getting a redirect and may need the cookie jar:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
```

---

You may need to set the request header to match the Browser Request:

Create an array to put the Request Header Key Values
Fill in the Request array with exactly what is in the Request header of your upload.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

Add to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

---

**Checking the the headers in a Browser**

Then I use FireFox Inspector or Chrome Development Tool.

I go to the Network Tab

In FireFox I go to Settings and turn on "Enable Persistent logs"
In Chrome I click "Preserve log" on the Network Tab

Then I use the Browser to go wherever I want curl to go.

Now I can see every Request and Response including redirects and compare them with the save headers.

**Inspect: Step by Step**

- right click select Inspect Element
- Select the Network tab
- Refresh the page
- Select Documents (chrome) or HTML (firefox)
- Clear the list
- Post your upload
- Select the upload Request in the list of Requests

---

I use FireFox with user agent switcher using an old Motorola user agent to retrieve the headers and HTML.  Then I use the same user agent in curl's `HTTPHEADER`:

```
request[] = 'User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
```

It is possible, not likely, the above cased the error when I tried

Comment: Why not? What kind of response did you get?  Did you compare your request and response headers to the ones in your Browser as explained in my post?

Comment: the post data not fill in the form and submit it.

Comment: Do you understand the HTTP Request and Response Headers?

Comment: Understanding HTTP Headers is a necessity  when trying to do this.  I have shown you one that I got to work, just to confirm it is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75671/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-max-cheng).

Answer (score 0):

Your Query String `$post_string` is right but you are missing to prepend it with `?` before sending curl. Try following:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?".$post_string);
```

Comment: when i echo $result; it print the whole page of Air Asia instead return me the flight info. Is it  other way to the flight info?

Comment: whatever is present on `'https://booking.airasia.com/search.aspx'` will comeback in `$result` i.e. behavior of CURL itself.
You can achieve you result by either editing and printing the result required at `search.aspx` or create a new page that could serve you the required results. **Comment Again if this is not clear**

Comment: you can use html_dom_parser class to find all values from html. This is good class : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: 'https://booking.airasia.com/search.aspx' does not contain any flight info. it just contain search form.

Comment: @mex cheng, you are trying a i.e. not a API endpoint. This is not the way I don't see airasia.com API available. CURL doesn't work that way...please search for CURL Documentation. Your request should be like : http://prntscr.com/6ucpvh

Comment: Is it possible to get flight info from AirAsia by using Curl and web scraping technique?

Comment: do not use the "?".  The ? is used in GET data not POST, see `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` in the PHP manual under `curl_setopt` if you doubt me.